# Powershell - Delete subfolder(s) in folder with specific name(s) older than 30 days

Tags: powershell

stackoverflow,
I am trying to come up with a PoSh script to do a very specific task that has me beating my head against my desk here. I am pretty new to Powershell, and need some help here.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

I need to be able to search through a drive for a specific folder called "30 Day Toss" and delete any subfolder(s) inside of it that has a creationdate of over 30 days old.

Example:

P:\Project\2014\3D1004\Plan 1\30 Day Toss\Archive1

P:\Project\2014\3D1004\Plan 2\30 Day Toss\04-12-2014

The Archive1 folder above was created 10 days ago and doesn't need deleted.
The 04-12-2014 folder above was created over 30 days ago and needs deleted, along with all files/folders under it.

The Project, year, job number and plan number are all variable and change, so hard coding a search path isn't an option.

Any assistance would be greatly appricieated, thanks!

Comment: The date it was created or the date it was last modified?

Comment: The date the folder directly under "30 Day Toss" was created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so assuming that your folder structure is always the same, and you always want the 6th level of folder or subfolders of that, this will work:

```
gci P:\ -directory -recurse | ?{$_.FullName -match ".:\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\" -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}|Remove-Item -recurse -whatif
```

That looks at the entire P: drive for folders, if the folder name is:

```
P:\<anything>\<anything>\<anything>\<anything>\<anything>\<anything>
```

It checks to see if it was created over 30 days ago, and if so it deletes it and all of it's contents. But it has to have that many levels for the script to look at it.

**Edit:** Ok, let's change it up a little. If the folder we're looking inside of is always called "30 Day Toss" we'll look for all folders with that name, and then pull a listing of things inside each of them. Easy enough! First, the code:

```
gci P:\ -Directory -Recurse | ?{$_.Name -ieq "30 Day Toss"} | %{GCI $_.FullName | ?{$_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-30)} | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force}
```

Then to break it down a little.

First we get a listing of all folders on the P: drive. Then we select only the ones named "30 day toss" (not case sensitive).

For each folder we find with that name we pull a directory listing for whatever is inside that folder, and then select only the things older than 30 days. For each of those things that are older than 30 days we delete them, and anything inside them.

Comment: Sorry I should have said that the path and folder depth is not the same throughout. We have a lot of old/current projects that have unpredictable folder structure.

Comment: So one project can be:

P:\Project\Year\Proj_Num\Plan\30 Day Toss

Another can be:

P:\Location\Project\Year\Proj_Num\Plan\30 Day Toss

You get the drift. Total mess.

Comment: Then how exactly would you know what folders to include? If there is no set structure then it really can't be scripted. Now, if it is always `<something, maybe several folders>\Year\Proj_Num\Plan*\Proj_Name` then that's something we can work with.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of. Because of our unpoliced project folder structure for many years, they vary. I would say 66% are correct, but the others are too random to predict.

Ultimatley, I was hoping we would be able to do something such as:

Search for all folders called "30 Day Toss". Look for folders one level below that. If a folder inside of the "30 Day Toss" folder has a creationdate are over 30 days old, delete said folder and all contents.

Comment: Oh, so the folder to look in is always called "30 Day Toss"? We can do that.

Comment: Awesome! That seems to do the trick. I placed the -WhatIf into the Remove-Item and ran a test to see what it came up with. I spot checked a lot of the folders, and they all were ones to be deleted.

This seems to be exactly what I needed. Doing all of the nested piping is where I was getting lost. I am only on like Chapter 6 of learn PoSH in 30 Days of Lunches :D

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-30)

$folders = gci "p:\" -filter "30 Day Toss" -recurse

Foreach ($subfolder in $folders.FullName) { gci $subfolder  | where {$_.psiscontainer} | where { $_.CreationTime -lt $date} | remove-item -force -recurse }
```

Comment: Sorry.. my english is not so good, maybe i have missunderstood something, but.. what is wrong with my answer?