# Log what is deleted

Tags: powershell

I'm very new to this but I have a problem with deleting 30days old files which I found an answer to here: [Powershell - Delete subfolder(s) in folder with specific name(s) older than 30 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23940903/powershell-delete-subfolders-in-folder-with-specific-names-older-than-30-d/36398899#36398899)

But I would like to make a follow question on that. 
The  code I use is this:

```
gci P:\ -directory -recurse | ?{$_.FullName -match ".:\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\" -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-30)}|Remove-Item -recurse -whatif
```

Is it possible to log what is deleted as well? Would be awesome if the size of the files are included in the log file. Thanks!

Comment: Of course it is possible. Just replace the `Remove-Item ...` part with `ForEach-Object {  }` and put the log and the remove commands in the brackets.

Comment: Don't really understand what you mean. I just started looking at powershell last week.
ForEach-Object {Remove-Item -recurse -force 'C:\path\to\deleted.log'} or am I way off?(Don't really know how to log)

Comment: No. He meant something like this: `... | ForEach-Object { "deleting $($_.FullName)" > 'C:\path\to\deleted.log'; Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse -Force }`

Comment: Is the outcome different from verbose?

Comment: Also how can I just log what is about to be deleted without delete it?

Comment: The output might be different, depending on what the input is. It's also simpler to just use verbose output, because it's a single statement instead of two statements and a loop. As for logging what would be deleted: see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the remove operation verbose and redirect the [verbose stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/03/30/understanding-streams-redirection-and-write-host-in-powershell/) to a file:

```
... | Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose 4> 'C:\path\to\your.log'
```

Note that this requires at least PowerShell v3.

If you only want to log what would be deleted without actually deleting it, use `-WhatIf` instead of `-Verbose`:

```
... | Remove-Item -Recurse -WhatIf
```

You can also combine the two:

```
$dryrun = $true   # set to $false to actually delete
... | Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose -WhatIf:$dryrun 4> 'C:\path\to\your.log'
```

However, `-WhatIf` output goes to the host console, so it can't be redirected to a file. You could use `Start-Transcript` as a workaround, but that would record everything, not just the would-be deletes. Or you could run the entire code/script (without redirections) in a new PowerShell process:

```
powershell.exe -File 'C:\path\to\your.ps1' > 'C:\path\to\your.log'
```

The host output of a child PowerShell process is merged into its STDOUT, so you can redirect it "from the outside".

Comment: Also how can I just log what is about to be deleted without deleting it?
I'm really new to this and can only find different ways to delete..

Comment: Can't get the log without delete to work. It creates the file.log but its empty.    
`$dryrun = $true   # set to $false to actually delete
gci D:\Shared\transfer -recurse | ?{$_.FullName -match ".:\\.+?\\.+?\\.+?\\" -and $_.CreationTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-15)}|Remove-Item -Recurse -Verbose -WhatIf:$dryrun 4>&1 > 'C:\Scripts\transferfolder\WhatWillBeDeleted.log'`

Comment: My mistake. `-WhatIf` output goes to the host console and can thus not be redirected like other streams. See updated answer.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot!